# HTML 5 phone number validation with pattern

Tags: html

i want to validate the phone number in pakistan format by using html 5 with pattern attribute.

the valid pakistan phone number format is :

+92 345 1234567

but when i entered this in the input field then it show me the following error:
please match the requested format

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

    <title> Web Course </title>

</head>

<body>

     <form>


         Enter your phone number:
        <input type="text"  pattern="[+][0-9]{2}[][0-9]{3}[][0-9]{7}"  />



        <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't check for spaces. Use `[ ]` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following solutions:

```html
<form>
  Enter your phone number (with spaces):
  <input type="tel" pattern="[+][0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{7}">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form>
  Enter your phone number (without spaces):
  <input type="tel" pattern="[+][0-9]{12}">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form>
  Enter your phone number (with or without spaces):
  <input type="tel" pattern="[+][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{7}">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need to brackets in `[ ]`, the space alone is enough. Also you can use `?` instead of `{0,1}`: `"[+][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{7}"`

Comment: Also you can use ? instead of {0,1}: "[+][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{7}
i did not get this ... what is the purpose of of question mark (?) here ?

Comment: The ? indicates zero or one occurrences of the preceding element. In this case no space or one space but not two or more spaces.